# Threads are freezing main form

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

I want to run multiple thread. Each thread should convert JPEG to Bitmap. Conversion works but my whole application is always using 12%-13% of CPU. I have an 8 core CPU so it seems the whole application uses just a single core. Also while the threads are working the main form is frozen and doesn't respond.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Jpeg, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Str: TMemoryStream;
    procedure OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TMakeThumbThread= class(TThread)
  private
    FStream: TStream;
  public
    FBmp: TBitmap;    
    constructor Create(Str: TStream);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMakeThumbThread.Create(Str: TStream);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FStream := Str;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TMakeThumbThread.Execute;
var Jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  FBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  FBmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  FBmp.Width := 300;
  FBmp.Height := 200;

  Jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
  FStream.Position := 0;
  Jpg.LoadFromStream(FStream);
  FBmp.Canvas.Draw(0,0, Jpg);
  Jpg.Free;

  DoTerminate;
  FBmp.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var F: TFileStream;
    i: Integer;
    MT: TMakeThumbThread;
begin
  Str := TMemoryStream.Create;
  F := TFileStream.Create('test.jpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Str.CopyFrom(F, F.Size);
  F.Free;

  for i:=0 to 500 do begin
    MT := TMakeThumbThread.Create(Str);
    MT.OnTerminate := OnTerminate;
    MT.Execute;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TMakeThumbThread(Sender).FBmp;
  Form1.Canvas.Draw(1,1, Bmp );
end;

end.
```

Comment: You must learn to protect your objects. **Never** write `X := TX.Create; {a lot of code} X.Free`. **Always** write `X := TX.Create; try {a lot of code} finally X.Free; end`. (And it seems like in one case, you forgot `Free` altogether.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are manually calling the thread's `Execute()` method in the context of the main thread. DON'T DO THAT! That is why your UI is freezing. You are creating your threads in a suspended state and never resuming them.

You need to change this line:

```
MT.Execute;
```

To either this:

```
MT.Resume;
```

Or this:

```
MT.Start;
```

Depending on which version of Delphi you are using.

There are several other problems with your code, too.

- The VCL's `TBitmap` class is not entirely thread-safe. You MUST `Lock()` the `TBitmap.Canvas` when working with a `TBitmap` in a worker thread, to prevent the main thread from ripping GDI resources away from the `TBitmap` unexpectedly.
- You are sharing a single `TMemoryStream` with multiple threads to have them all load the same JPG image simultaneously. That will not work unless you wrap access to the `TMemoryStream` with a synchronization object, like a `TCriticalSection` or `TMutex`. Or, another option would be to use `TCustomMemoryStream` to create multiple streams that share a single memory block. Otherwise, you would be better off simply passing the JPG filename to each thread and let `Execute()` call `TJpegImage.LoadFromFile()` instead of `TJpegImage.LoadFromStream()`.
- You are calling `FBmp.Free()` at the end of `Execute()`, but then you are accessing `FBmp` afterwards in the `OnTerminate` event handler. You need to delay the call to `FBmp.Free()` until after the `OnTerminate` event handler exits, such as in the thread's destructor.
- You are drawing the bitmaps directly on the `TForm.Canvas` from outside of the Form's `OnPaint` event. As such, as soon as your Form need to redraw itself for *any* reason, your drawn images will be lost. If you want the images to be persistent for the Form's lifetime, you need to save them and draw them whenever the `OnPaint` event fires. Or, you can simply assign them to `TImage` components and let them handle the drawing for you.

Comment: It did help! Thanks a lot. Do you know, by any chance, how to convert JPEG to a bitmap without TBitmap?

Comment: @Tom That is a totally different unrelated question. Please don't expect it to get answered in the comments of another answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge I expected sort of "can't be done" quick answer. But you are right.

Comment: @Tom why do you need to convert it to a BMP at all? You can `Draw()` the original JPG as-is onto your Form.

Comment: It can be done, just not with TJpeg. Have a look at external DLLs, like LibJpeg (or rather LibJpeg Turbo) or OpenCV. These work on memory buffers. But beware: There is quite a steep learning curve even if you manage to find the import units for Delphi. On the other hand: Why do yo want to do that? If TJPEG/TBitmap works for you, stick with it. Having said that: LibJpeg Turbo is much faster, so if performance becomes an issue, this is defintively a way to go.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need to convert it into a bitmap to work with it further (eg. make it grayscale).